# how to combine two tables not the same values in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i combine two tables that one of the tables has another i want to add to the two tables ?

For example ,
[image]

I have these two tables , ID-matchs and theID  , i want to combine it to be the one on the right , as if the total match is null- to but a default value of -0

I've tried somethink like this -

```
Select distinct  k.ID,
matchSum 
from theID as k, ID-matchs
```

but it gave me the 
Cartesian Multiply .

Comment: mysql or (MS)sql-Server?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sql-server , but how is it different if i'm writing it in sql ? :)

Comment: @reeena11 There are big differences between the DBMS

Comment: Perhaps not in this specific case, but still no need for other dbms product tags,

Comment: i've edited it , thank you

Comment: You should search for `join`

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Using only a comma, without an on clause, will cross join (for reference)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce` to get your desired result.

```
    SELECT t1.Id,
               Coalesce(t2.matches, 0) as Matches
        FROM theId t1
        LEFT JOIN IDmatchs t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
        order by t1.Id;
```

You can check demo [here](http://rextester.com/MUGZHK31184)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
  B.ID,
  ISNULL(A.Matches, 0) as Matches
FROM
  TABLEA as A
  LEFT JOIN TABLEB as B
    on A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UNION

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT *, ISNULL(matches,0) FROM table2
```

Or the other way around with the isnull to replace null with 0, I'm not sure what the table names are.